# Machine failure Prediction

Tags: machine-learning, data-science, forecasting, predicate

I want to predict the machine failure.
My data frame contain two columns, first one date and second one logical(0 for working and 1 for failure) ex.

```
  Data              label
12/5/2015            0
13/5/2015            1
14/5//2015           0
15/5/2015            0
```

based on above data frame I want to predict the failure date one day in advance, please let me know which model i should use to predict the failure date.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you are not going to be able to make a meaningful prediction with just this type of data.  You should consider moving towards a richer data set that might include additional features such as things like: 'operational hours', 'days since last service', 'average operating temperature', etc.
Normally, for these types of predictions you would want to have several features that you believe are relevant to what you want to predict.